# How to get executable shared library list from C++?

Tags: c++, posix, shared-libraries, ld, procfs

I'd like to programmatically get a list of the shared libraries linked by my binary on Linux and Solaris. Right now I shell out to pmap (I can't use `ldd` on the binary because it won't include dlopen'd libraries, and I can't use `pldd` because it's Solaris only):

```
std::ostringstream cmd;
cmd << "/usr/bin/pmap " << getpid() << " | awk '{ print $NF }' | grep '\\.so' | sort -u";
FILE* p = popen(cmd.str().c_str(), "r");
```

This is a bit hackish but it works on both Solaris and Linux (the pmap output is slightly different but the desired info is always in the last column). Is there a way to get the same information without shelling out? That works on both platforms? I assume the `/proc/$PID` files are formatted differently between them but I don't know where the headers for helping parse those are usually located (if there's a common location at all?).

Comment: Strictly speaking `dlopen`ed libraries aren't "linked", they're loaded at runtime. I assume you actually want a list of all the loaded shared libraries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pmap 1234` command with `1234` being a process id.

From inside your program, the simpler way (Linux-specific) is to read and parse the `/proc/self/maps` file.

Try running

> `cat /proc/self/maps`

under Linux: it will show you the memory mapping of the process running the `cat` command above.

And if you've got some precise pointer, you can use `dladdr` (a GNU/Linux or Glibc specific function) to get information about which dynamic library contains it.